# What does the graph of MO questions-and-links look like?

Tags: discussion, statistics, linked-questions

Consider the graph $G$ whose vertices are MO questions and edges are links between the questions. What does $G$ look like?

I'm happy to define a "link" in the same way the SE software seems to -- if a hyperlink to Question A is written anywhere in the text of Question B or its answers, or the comments to either Question B or its answers, then Question A will pop up in the "Linked Questions" sidebar on Question B, and *also* Question B will pop up in the "Linked Questions" sidebar on Question A (the graph is undirected).

- $G$ is very far from connected. It has many nodes (perhaps the majority?) with no edges at all.
- What is the largest connected component of $G$? Are the component sizes distributed according to a power law or something?
- What is the maximum degree of a node in $G$? How are the degrees of nodes distributed?
- How does this graph structure compare to the tag structure or the user structure (I'm not sure of the best way to make this question precise)?
- What happens if we add to $G$ nodes for arxiv preprints or journal articles and links from MO questions to them?

I think that studying the structure of $G$ will not shed as much light on the structure of MO as, say, studying the link structure of the Internet as a whole sheds on the Internet, since links as defined here are not the only way questions can be related. But it still seems interesting.

Probably these sorts of questions have been considered thoroughly by the developers at SE, as the structure of $G$ is presumably an important ingredient in generating the "Related Questions" sidebar.

Comment: Somewhat related (but not the same) question on [math.meta.se]: [How to obtain the math.SE network whose edges are linked questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16697) Maybe somebody familiar with Mathematica would be able to say whether it could be useful here: [Studying the MathOverflow data dump with Mathematica](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4113).

Comment: Some older posts with links to various resources studying MO: [On Mathematical Analysis of MathSciNet & MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/301299), [Papers, articles, books and other resources discussing MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4114). But I did not notice there something related specifically to the linked questions.

Comment: The paper "Social achievement and centrality in MathOverflow", Complex Networks IV, Studies in Computational Intelligence Volume 476, 2013, 27-38 by Leydi Viviana Montoya, Athen Ma and Raul J. Mondragón, studying something like this graph, was mentioned in [an answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1896/41291) to my question ["Is MO connected?"](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1894/41291).

Answer (score 11):

I can answer this part of the question with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

> What is the maximum degree of a node in $G$? How are the degrees of nodes distributed?

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1374001/questions-with-the-most-links) shows a list of questions with the most links.

| Question | Number of links |
| --- | --- |
| [Proposals for polymath projects](https://mathoverflow.net/q/219638/70594) | 48 |
| [Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23478/70594) | 47 |
| [Not especially famous, long-open problems which anyone can understand](https://mathoverflow.net/q/100265/70594) | 40 |
| [Important formulas in combinatorics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/214927/70594) | 30 |

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1374012/distribution-of-the-number-of-linked-questions#graph) is a graph showing the distribution (NOTE: the y-axis is logarithmic):

[image]

Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

---

> as the structure of $G$ is presumably an important ingredient in generating the "Related Questions" sidebar.

No, that would be nice but it isn't. It's based on a similarity algorithm in Elastic, the 'database' powering Stack Exchange search. See [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/295232) for more information.

Comment: I see that the query uses UNION to solve the problem that the PostLinks table is not symmetric (+1).

Comment: I just wanted to check whether I understand correctly understand the PostLinks table - it contains only the questions shown as the linked posts, not all links, right?  Linked questions can be [missing for various reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287417/why-does-a-question-sometimes-not-appear-among-the-linked-questions), in the case of MO this is likely the case for [many posts before 2013](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4585/retroactively-add-linked-questions).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I remember I had to ask rene why my cross-site query with `UNION` did not work as expected. It turns out I needed `UNION ALL` ... And your observation about old linked posts is correct. I'm pretty sure that's not doable without scraping the website / API and extract all the links.

Comment: All roads lead to polymath, it seems. But that just might be a common false belief. In either case, that seems like an open problem that is easy to explain, and solving it would involve important formulas from combinatorics.